# How to allow access only to logged in users restricting direct entry of url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

in a Rubyonrails application i want only  logged in users to enterinto the inner pages?
how can i redirect the direct entered urls to index page?

in php if(!isset($_SESSION[id]) { header("location:index.php") }, how this can be implemented in ruby on rails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here goes

**In application_controller.rb:**

Putting this code in application_controller will make it available to all your controllers.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  protected

def confirm_logged_in
    unless session[:id]
        flash[:notice] = "Please log in"
        redirect_to :root
        return false
    else
        return true
    end
end

end
```

**Then you can make use of this method in any of the controllers that require it, for eg**

If you need to confirm that users are logged in for the show action, then

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_filter :confirm_logged_in, :only => [:show]

def show
    #all your code
end

end
```

should work, as this will confirm that users accessing this show url have logged in.

For more info checkout this link to [rails guides on filters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters). There could be more efficient ways of achieving this as well.

However, i would suggest using a gem like [Cancan](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) ([Github](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)) as i have used this in many apps and works well. The code presented above is basic and there are many better and advanced ways to handle this but it should do the job.Hope it helps.