# Rails: Restrict access to specific pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I followed [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch) tutorial, and it works. But how can I restrict a page so that only users that are logged in can access it?

I wrote `<% if current_user %>` at the top of one page and if I tried to access it when I wasn't logged in, I could not access it (so this is one solution). But, is there a way I can do this in the controller? (I tried to use a before_filter as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500350/how-to-allow-access-only-to-logged-in-users-restricting-direct-entry-of-url) post, but it did not work).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ActionController` [before_filter](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) to validate the user by checking the existence of the `current_user` method.

Answer (score 0):

if using Devise, you can add

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

to your controller.